# Processor Group level resource consumption in Nifi

Tags: java, jmx, apache-nifi

In the current project setup, we see the nifi level resource consumption and pattern using :

```
http://server1:8080/nifi-api/system-diagnostics
```

Has anyone implemented Process Group level resource monitoring ( Memory, CPU etc.) in apache nifi ?
I could not find any way of implementing it using the API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new feature in the upcoming Apache NiFi 1.6.0 ([NIFI-4849](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2468/files)) allows for per-processor diagnostics via the API. This will return information including garbage collection statistics, queue size, bytes processed (last 5 minutes), etc. NiFi does not measure hardware consumption (memory, CPU, etc.) on a per-processor (|group) basis.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Yes, since Nifi works within a single JVM instance for all processors/(groups), i understand reporting hardware consumption at processor level is not possible. But, the rest of the stats should help us monitor the health of the flow.